# Compiling C++ with one C function in GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, header-files

Using gcc, I want to call one C function, declared in a .c file, in a .cpp program. The command I'm using is:

`gcc {.cpp files} -lstdc++ {.c file}`

I couldn't just convert the C file to CPP, but if I include a common header one of two things naturally happens:

1. The CPP files don't understand what a C header is
2. The C file doesn't understand what a CPP header is.

How do I do this? Can I somehow compile the C function before and then use it?

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know C++. Encapsulate the declaration of the C function in a `extern "C"` block to prevent the C++ compiler to name-mangle the C function.. Maybe something like `extern "C" {` `#include <header.c>` `}`

Comment: For one the .h file is usually what is used to expose the interfaces. The interfaces are effectively a list of symbols (names/signatures). C and C++ use a different mechanism to uniquely generate the symbols mainly C++ mangles the symbols, so the two cannot understand each other. As @pmg mentioned you will need to tell C++ that the method is from C so it will use the right symbol from C, and I believe you will need to extern the C++ symbol you want to use in C differently. here is a reference: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp

Comment: The `g++` toolchain driver can compile C files, and be used to link C files to C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that C++ allows overloading of methods.  To allow this, the compiler tags the method name to indicate the types of parameters that can be passed (so-called "name mangling").

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use `extern C` declarations in any C++ method calling C.  To allow C to call C++, you need an `extern C` method in the C++ source to allow it to be called from C.  Make sense?

Structure your header accordingly so that it can be included from both C and C++ sources:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

... // body of header

#ifdef __cplusplus
    } // closing brace for extern "C"

#endif
```

For more info see:
https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/mixing-c-and-cplusplus.html

and
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extern-c-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this, one has to understand how are C and C++ languages compiled. I will not attempt to explain it here, [others have already done much better job that I can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work). So, I will just mention the relevant parts.

There is nothing special about C or C++ headers, `#include` literally just pastes the file contents (recursively).

Every translation unit (~ one .c{pp} file and all included headers) is compiled separately into an object file containing symbol tables and (almost) compiled code.

What is likely causing the issue is either C or C++ specific code in header files   (neither language is a superset of the other) or C++ symbol mangling - as pointed out by @pmg. There is not much that can be done with the former. The latter can solved using `extern "C"`

foo.h

```c
void foo(void);
```

foo.c

```c
#include "foo.h"

#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void){
    printf("Hello from C\n");
}
```

Running `gcc -c foo.c` will create `foo.o` that contains the implementation for the function symbol `foo`.

main.cpp

```cpp
extern "C"{
#include "foo.h"
}
int main(){
   foo();
}
```

Similarly, `g++ -c main.cpp`  will create `main.o` object file.

Then, running `g++ -o program.out main.o foo.o` will link them together into `program.out` executable.

```
> ./program.out
Hello from C
```

`extern "C"{}` disables symbol mangling and because the included code is just  pasted there, it is applied to the whole file. So, `main.o` function symbol table says that it seeks `foo` function symbol instead of `_Z3foov` or something similar.